# How can I use my plotted data in further calculations?

Tags: arrays, pine-script

So I have this code that draws zigzag-alike line

```
indicator("Custom zigzag", overlay=true)
bullish(at) => open[at] < close[at]
bearish(at) => open[at] > close[at]
break_up() => 
    if close != open
        at = 1
        while close[at] == open[at]
            at += 1
        if bearish(at) and bullish(0)
            true
        else
            false
    else
        false
break_down() => 
    if close != open
        at = 1
        while close[at] == open[at]
            at += 1
        if bearish(0) and bullish(at)
            true
        else
            false
    else
        false
u = break_up()
d = break_down()

plot(u?open[0] : d?open[0] : na, color = color.fuchsia, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_line, offset=0)
```

I want to use the result in some further calculations, but I dont get it, how can I put the whole `u?open[0] : d?open[0] : na` in an array?
Roughly pushing values to an array variable leads to recalculation on each bar, IMO.
Or can I access somehow my own previous plot, since custom script call is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it depending on do you want na values as it is or previous calculated values in place of na. You can save the whole thing in a variable and then use that to calculate anything like sma etc. First way

```
//Keeping na value
val=u?open[0] : d?open[0] : na
s=ta.sma(val,10)
plot(s)
```

Second way

```
//Replacing na values with previous values
var val=open[0]
val:=u?open[0] : d?open[0] : val[1]
s=ta.sma(val,10)
plot(s)
```

Comment: yes, the first one is what I needed, I should just store the calculations in variable, and then pass the latter to the plot function, and then do next whatever I needed